# Convert ES6 javascript file to ES5 online

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert a ES6 javascript file to ES5 as I'm need to target an old browser (ie: A webview on Android 4.4.2).

I've seen that Babeljs.io provide a tool to do a conversion, but the output code don't seems valid...  ([see here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=PQKgBGDOCuDGsFNKTAajAQwDYIE4Bc0wB3DXAOwEtyBzIgWyUgxoTBGACgIA3MqBPgDK-AJ44UAXjAAKBFgA0UMRICUYSQD4wAb24QwAeQBGAKwSx8AOgDWCUZBmQVSVVYBmAe1wBRDLAALGRk7UXUtXX0DMHkrZ3EEAG1QgF0NZQTIZPsUgG4osABfVXyIQvz9WE9yZwF8AEF8fFwpWXklDCaW8O09aJNzS1t7R07myDcvX38gkPseyOiIWMhBRubKY2h8BDnRDq6s1JKC4tKiiogqmsJWBq70uUVMLoXYu_XcTe3dsdwTyrVWoABy-fB2AGkRuk-gYACYIdwYaBYfCGYH4ShAgBcYCEonoxk8WBkAHIEUiUWiMViaqTVAoCrgEOQEbhcfjCcSyczWXh6YzopAAp5iByCUSSaThaKBQUApQEeKuVKFQi5dFmfRPDwEAARQwAWWVkp5CG1uoNho1F04gJuUEoTvowJwABVPBhatJYRBEqDKOCEFCHFYKcjUejMUCUrjfQZrvgMNQ8LjSUS4aJSYKlrAsF7IGnIE7KC73Z7nNmChBgZ5i9HyGn8J5gQAfRDkHa4KtLMD0Mg0ai4gCMAFYc9EEfnRLiAAwT-HQXCdWm4gDMs83C4g8RwccKC4PdqFgijtMcLYbrR0xUWS2Z-CX5Dvvasb-LztdCA9Xvw24M_pgp0wYjGGiIRtSV6xi-vZgG-Vj4AqWQBkGIaQGBlKRjSMb_tE8GXueuFFP-5SnIyBSAYGwFoVYvJsikThJjsSiMMgLAIEoBFAjCt7xlcQKEIwuCsHCZ7cT61YGPBiGUMhQGQqB4ZUmJNQpER-HYTUJGXLmAkwdEeYFrihnIAAchgjBEbW9a0kRU4YPskkQHCS4rtURG7hxkmFOkQkiSpkA6QZenkAgxA_t6YBwp4sDQIwnZWLAzLAT4ODxfgZJwoG9JBQYwDAGAWCeDQg60GAPCUBgLzjJJoXhRW1gmZA5mMOkTUtQguV8Lgyi4MO6SkgAPJAwIYM-TWSAARM2v4AJLXGApKoM4wGoKSk2aKSuX5WAlDXCg6A7C6kAFJQ7iMcBkhTTA8BMJN6h8eV_DOLgABMA2DZQYATZNSI9UiAC0gQWDYQOULgeYIBtg3AJQm3nNE3VgEdwKtKOm6zrkYA7aOAiwKcBTyKsu3nStOxXZN2B4Pg936U9PUve90hDV9P1IiggOYqxYMQzg0Ow_DklIyjrTDhjmPYwVYt4wT0RE2wZ0XeTU2kBQ1A0LTj1I4zH2s_myBTezYCAwgAAehn9g2AMbGNNB85oMNw1tQv8CL6RixjWM7dLqz49EhSE1gxNa89zRM4tn3ffrkCG16xsYAD1BeDzkP807CMGML5qo-74te1Ls4y_7BTa80a4fcAI1jQ7VfjdHU0zc4bpmzTm2oKxzCsGtMO14LJeh7gAAsH1VQEzLuFNk1RwWDcNQAwkVqzQ3rM-_XHnOlkgacO8AGB94jruevgkAADKegicKSMOGd1RF1jUKFuAABJuoaJ_pC9w6JdUsCdIxb1KBemuQBzRB4Al7Kse44wZC3wakoR6EBySdATtZSgDZSS4lQQ2IiSCkwAzJggDByhgIkROBAwQIhMgwLCnfEBCQyFLB2tAYmcRBBuk3p4bYMh1DUGcAgDAcIwCeHcGAAAJFYAAjtABA0juGSRwIQLmbBpCY0kpA9hjBOEZW4RoXoTlkZIUoqhUCMpiAMVgb-FieB_KaQmBnMoSglFoGkPZMI9i6gaIQFo4ICwEEGNkkY6ioE1QIHMTQuBfZrEIFErYhh_tHGb2ccjbOdjjyMIKjAYEtYCCRMQp4QRgRkxUFoJJB8T5_GBTImkv0KEgmhlMQxdouhvrVCTCmXASgmrGWjh1FiA5qBFAepJfahAAhegAAp1keDwJQ1kFgfC6DIGZi04TIIBlg2k9IrDUARKbQw505lgG0ADa-1SEx6VwJ4TwhAXExTiiyawUi8CiCEPICwzZcAyETEUvAcSDCXOudsmo1MABCiJvC7CaQC6w7hwbODngqLAcJwHpLqLtKgmJsBgA2dUNRFCXCOCaX4nFjYWmdh-T1K6zMMxZjAAAfkWrC020TSRgDTBgYwkBiQ_B7LBRIYzICTMJc8UkzZgT0npYtMVrK0xEiaJ4egpJoKkhOZuYEpteW9n5RMusTwlCkhwO4fAEqABkJrFqGuNcqsc6rNVLG1YK3VTTSQdi7Ka81BrERWtxAAA1EToGQ0LEpYEoA8gA6oqRC2MwCvXUADNoWBg2hs7BGuEUaCqxsKOqn1REHVCr1YtL4NAAjGvUGawtlBi3esWjajVpDco7nxVQol-jmhjUgFMegRZf44BkMOVQdrogtn8GgmcYBhz1rORAHaWUVrkEQFFNgcIACXo0cnyMENi5hAQRD-BsOkV6qjJL1FwMuUQ-iPCXPoDIaKsV0qSOkbgF5bzLDeHqFgEkPqrD-vahZBAhREirLwSSqa_qFnNALbglBdY0GbNUIUSaKQfWqFUBe2FqI8AyEbjc7Q2GrBroealc0DyNBXRiImgjnYiPpVUDtS2gR1ZkraY_ND3g_CBGCNh3x-jG3CAJVhiJfjoh5t1dh_V0r1AMtFS2GVi05XNkVdBP1OhgTbt3bAGwWbTY5p44MhtSxVPCnU_u1A0g8PCPcJAp-CBK0loYP08g7iyh_KPBRWpClQwhMaVgIZvYRlgAFUK6Zsy6zzLWIs5ZUH1kwfQW4HZZt9kyEOcc05fm9I6EKl6pQxBI0BCKOkd4ggQWcNZOrBeyb8AACV3ncP05AyhEgC1-JE8K_Vlr3UWq9Uq31_qctpoCFpnTsEwAtcg66_kZaPXtaU_6y1RA-uIUG7mwLTqRVFpLR10k63q0-oBr13LS39HDtgKOuck7hl6WIAEFkbplw1Fg9UHwrJHjceGzJOSVEPPoS1DqfURpvN_Llomn7uofC6k7CfWSOxH5kjbfdhsLI4TZhINd8gt320PfIE95F7jSKSViAIuEYOHmQ74TD0Vd2bLVER8jq7N3KeY-xy58iwn3MgVDCDv7hoAe6B2kgENnYAazo5TgAGAuEAXYdJRm55H8NkEI2lB57jpe0XNL9hFlAkVPGZ2cpSqIZAd3YpxWJdMykUAqYEr7qu-S4AYuScCVJkeG9YMbq8OuhRwEQMgA3TAjdCJN49M3z53uW_Z99xHeA7c3S95AJ3vuXf-7dxnI80QqYEB92xBPXEai-fvIIcpIe2c0TopHskafjVWMzxxRP553cGFVsUmgGfO7V-zxMU3-fzeF_kmH639EyQN_VnHqvrva_J5zKRIAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.13.7&externalPlugins=))

Any idea how to achieve this conversion (just once) ?

The file concerned is siiimple-toast.js (a toast notification plugin)

```
/*  success + alert + warning + message */
  var setStyles = (el, styles) => {
    Object.keys(styles).forEach((key) => {
      el.style[key] = styles[key];
    });
  };

  const setAttrs = (el, attrs) => {
    Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key) => {
      el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
    });
  };

  const getAttr = (el, attr) => el.getAttribute(attr);

  const privateKeys = {
    defaultOptions: Symbol('defaultOptions'),
    render: Symbol('render'),
    show: Symbol('show'),
    hide: Symbol('hide'),
    removeDOM: Symbol('removeDOM'),
  };

  const siiimpleToast = {
    [privateKeys.defaultOptions]: {
      container: 'body',
      class: 'siiimpleToast',
      position: 'top|center',
      margin: 15,
      delay: 0,
      duration: 3000,
      style: {},
    },

    setOptions(options = {}) {
      return {
        ...siiimpleToast,
        [privateKeys.defaultOptions]: {
          ...this[privateKeys.defaultOptions],
          ...options,
        },
      };
    },

    [privateKeys.render](state, message, options = {}) {
      const mergedOptions = {
        ...this[privateKeys.defaultOptions],
        ...options,
      };

      const {
        class: className,
        position,
        delay,
        duration,
        style,
      } = mergedOptions;

      const newToast = document.createElement('div');

      // logging via attrs
      newToast.className = className;

      var toatsLoaded=1;
      newToast.innerHTML = '<span class="toastIcon '+state+'">';

      setAttrs(newToast, {
        'data-position': position,
        'data-state': state,
      });
      setStyles(newToast, style);
      // use .setTimeout() instead of $.queue()
      let time = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this[privateKeys.show](newToast, mergedOptions);
      }, time += delay);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this[privateKeys.hide](newToast, mergedOptions);
      }, time += temps);

      // support method chaining
      return this;
    },

    [privateKeys.show](el, { container, class: className, margin }) {
      const hasPos = (v, pos) => getAttr(v, 'data-position').indexOf(pos) > -1;

      const root = document.querySelector(container);
      root.insertBefore(el, root.firstChild);

      // set initial position
      setStyles(el, {
        position: container === 'body' ? 'fixed' : 'absolute',
        [hasPos(el, 'top') ? 'top' : 'bottom']: '-100px',
        [hasPos(el, 'left') && 'left']: '15px',
        [hasPos(el, 'center') && 'left']: `${(root.clientWidth / 2) - (el.clientWidth / 2)}px`,
        [hasPos(el, 'right') && 'right']: '15px',
      });

      setStyles(el, {
        transform: 'scale(1)',
        opacity: 1,
      });

      // distance de départ 
      let pushStack = 20;

      Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${className}[data-position="${getAttr(el, 'data-position')}"]`))
        .filter(toast => toast.parentElement === el.parentElement)// matching container
        .forEach((toast) => {
          setStyles(toast, {
            [hasPos(toast, 'top') ? 'top' : 'bottom']: `${pushStack}px`,
          });

          pushStack += toast.offsetHeight + margin;
        });
    },

    [privateKeys.hide](el) {
      const hasPos = (v, pos) => getAttr(v, 'data-position').indexOf(pos) > -1;
      const { left, width } = el.getBoundingClientRect();

      setStyles(el, {
        [hasPos(el, 'left') && 'left']: `${width}px`,
        [hasPos(el, 'center') && 'left']: `${left + width}px`,
        [hasPos(el, 'right') && 'right']: `-${width}px`,
        opacity: 0,
      });

      const whenTransitionEnd = () => {
        this[privateKeys.removeDOM](el);
        el.removeEventListener('transitionend', whenTransitionEnd);
      };

      el.addEventListener('transitionend', whenTransitionEnd);
    },

    [privateKeys.removeDOM](el) {// eslint-disable-line
      const parent = el.parentElement;
      parent.removeChild(el);
    },
    default(message, options) {
      return this[privateKeys.render]('default', message, options);
    }
  };

  $(document).on('click', '.toastClose', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('.siiimpleToast').remove();
  });
```

Thanks a lot for your feedbacks

Ben

Comment: "Does not seem valid"? Please elaborate.

Comment: I see errors in my webview debbugging that refer to line 41 :
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ` 

When I try to validate the JS result (from babeljs) on JS code validators (ex here : codebeautify.org/jsvalidate), it reports errors...